# MySql - DROP table 'whatever' if exist ELSE create table 'whatever'?

Tags: mysql, create-table, sql-drop

I simply want to drop the table 'whatever' if it exist and then recreate table 'whatever' in a single query if possible.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `whatever` ELSE
    CREATE TABLE `whatever`
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE `whatever` IF NOT EXISTS ELSE TRUNCATE `whatever`
```

Use [TRUNCATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/truncate-table.html) to empty the table and reset cardinality instead of deleting the table and recreating it.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. My MySQL version is 5.5.17. How can I get this running ?